# Algorithm Question-why on average to be linear

Tags: algorithm

You are given a query point p and a set Q of n other points in two-dimensional space. Find k points out of the n points which are
nearest to p. Why on average this be linear?

Comment: If you use the [quickselect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm, it will be linear.  The fact that the points are in two dimensions doesn’t matter because you just calculate their distance from q using the Pythagorean function which is O(1).

Comment: Note quickselect is only expected linear time for random inputs; worst case O(n^2). There _do exist_ worst case linear time 1d nearest-k selection algorithms, but quickselect isn't one of them.

Comment: @Gene The question asks for something that is on average linear.  Therefore quickselect will work.